How do I pass a JSON twig template?
Symfony 7.
I have the following controller, which works fine:
 #[Route('/jsonnodes', name: 'app_nodes_jsonnodes', methods: ['GET'])]
 public function jsonnodes(NodesRepository $nodesRepository):  Response
    {
    $encoders = [new XmlEncoder(), new JsonEncoder()];
    $normalizers = [new ObjectNormalizer()];
    $serializer = new Serializer($normalizers, $encoders);
    $response = new Response();
    //$jsonContent = $serializer->serialize($nodesRepository->findAll(), 'json');

EDIT
I fixed things by a loop on what I get from the findAll()
   $array = $nodesRepository->findAll();  
     foreach ($array as &$value) {

     $string = "(".$value->getId() . ")--" .$value->getUnittitle().':'.'<a href="'.$this->generateUrl('app_nodes_show', ['id' => $value->getId()]).'">'.$value->getUnittitle().'</a> </br>';
     $value->setUnittitle($string);
     }
    $jsonContent = $serializer->serialize($array, 'json');

EDIT<<
    $jsonContent = str_replace("null", "\"#\"", $jsonContent);      
    
    /// BELOW TO BE REPLACED BY TWIG TEMPLATE
    $jsonContent = str_replace("fatherId", "parent", $jsonContent);
    $jsonContent = str_replace("id", "idd", $jsonContent);
    $jsonContent = str_replace("nodeId", "id", $jsonContent);
    $jsonContent = str_replace("unittitle", "text", $jsonContent);
     
 
    $response->setContent($jsonContent);
         $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
     return $response;         

Still I would like to use a jsonnodes.json.twig template, and have something like
    return new JsonResponse(      
    $this->renderView('nodes/jsonnodes.json.twig', [
        'nodes' => $nodesRepository->findAll()
    ])  
    );

but I don't fine a correct way to do it, either I miss to return a Response, or I return an empty string. Any idea?
(I need a json, to feed it into jstree.js)

Why do you want to use a template for this? Please clarify

Yeah I would recommend using a DTO that I turn into a json response instead of using a twig template

What's the reason of using template if all the data is dynamic? Template implies on having common static / repeatable parts

I think because I may tune better the final json (also, it does not look nice to me, to use str_replace within a controller).  Anyway, just out of curiosity, is there a way to do it?

I would not use twig to produce JSON. The whitespacing, tabbing and newlines would be so hard to control if you want "clean" output. Why don't you just build an array with the data that jstree requires and just json_encode that array. This will give you the "cleanest" output

Sorry for the late response on my part, please have a look at How do I access the Twig path() function from a Controller?

@DarkBee, Yes, it works, thanks. Actually, the issue is now with jstree.js, but that is for another post.
